# Qprocess and command MSDOS

Tags: qt, qprocess

I want execute a commande line with QProcess :

```
  QString elf_path=C:\\files\\file.elf;
  QString appli = "readelf.exe -a "+elf_path+" >>C:\\work\\essai.txt";
  QProcess *process = new QProcess();
  process->execute(appli);
```

but QT display this error :

```
 readelf: Error: '>>C:\work\essai.txt': No such file
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QProcess::execute command will take the first parameter as the executable and pass each of the next parameters as arguments to that executable. So the error is because the readelf executable is receiving ">>C:\work\essai.txt" as an argument.

There is more than one solution to fix this.

Rather than redirecting the output to the text file, you could read the output from the readelf command (readAllStandardOutput), open a file essai.txt from Qt and append the output yourself. You should probably call waitForFinished() before retrieving the output.

Alternatively, there's a function in QProcess called setStandardOutputFile which takes a filename to redirect the output from the process to that file, which may be easier: -

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess;
QString appli = "readelf.exe -a " + elf_path;
proc->setStandardOutputFile("C:\\work\\essai.txt", QIODevice::Append);
proc->start(appli);
```

Finally, you could create a shell script and call that with your parameters where the shell script would know that the final input parameter is to use for the output redirection.

Comment: I encountered another problem, normally the file must have a size of 4140 Ko, but with  the commands with QProcess, its size is just  521 Ko.

Comment: Which file - the redirected output?

Comment: Are you calling the process function waitForFinished? If not, give that a try.

Comment: i added      

 if(!proc->waitForStarted(-1)) {
            proc->close();
        }

after proc->start(appli);

and it works very well, thank you Merlin069

Answer (score 0):

QProcess::execute is static method. You should not create instance of QProcess in your case. Try next code

```
const QString path2exe = "readelf.exe";
QStringList commandline;
commandline << "-a";
commandline << elfPath;
commandline << "c:\\work\\essai.txt"
QProcess::execute( path2exe, commandline );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `readelf` is seeing your redirection as another file, which is valid since `readelf` can handle more than one on the command line.

Hence, the `Qt` process stuff is not handling redirection as you expect.

Within a shell of some sort, the redirections are used to set up standard input/output (and possibly others) *then* they're removed from the command line seen by the executable program. In other words, the executable normally doesn't see the redirection, it just outputs to standard output which the shell has connected to a file of some sort.

In order to fix this, you'll either have to run a `cmd` process which *does* understand redirection (passing the `readelf` command as a parameter) or use something like the method `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` to get the output into a byte array instead of writing to a temporary file.